# Are Chern-Simons theories classified by bordism groups?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, research-level, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

For a long time it was thought that anomalies for a group $G$ were classified by $H^n(BG)$, although it is now understood that they are in fact classified by $\Omega^n(BG)$.

On the other hand, [Dijkgraaf and Witten](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02096988) argue that Chern-Simons terms are classified by $H^4(BG)$, although given the relation between anomalies and Chern-Simons terms, it seems natural to ask whether Chern-Simons theories are better classified by $\Omega^4(BG)$ instead of $H^4$. **Is this correct?**

This would give a satisfying picture because bosonic theories would be classified by $\Omega^\text{SO}$ and fermionic ones by $\Omega^\text{Spin}$, or something like that. Perhaps the unoriented versions classify reflection-invariant TQFTs?

For example, [Seiberg et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10008) claim that $O(N)$ Chern-Simons theories are specified by $(k,L,p)\in\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z_8\times \mathbb Z_2$. Now the origin of the second factor is, as far as I can see, $\Omega^\text{Spin}_3(B\mathbb Z_2)=\mathbb Z_8$, so indeed it seems that bordism groups are related. Is perhaps $\Omega^\text{Spin}_3(BO(N))=\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z_8\times \mathbb Z_2$?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Chern-Simons terms classify pertubative anomalies, not global anomalies. Anomalies being classified by bordism groups was necessary to include global anomalies.

Comment: It is the eta invariant which completely classifies all anomalies. For most purposes the eta invariant can be replaced by a Chern-Simons term. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.08775.pdf is a good read regarding the eta invariant. Note the text near eqns 2.13 and 2.14.